# Uncaught exception error from chrome: cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I put together a HTML5 and javascript app but for some reason I am getting an exception error from chrome, and I have no idea why.

> Uncaught exception error from chrome: cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Here is my html

```
<section class="experiment">
<div class="inner" style="height: 5em;">
<audio id="audio" autoplay controls></audio>
<button class="recorder-btn" id="record-audio">Record</button>
<button class="recorder-btn" id="stop-recording-audio" disabled>Stop</button>
<h2 id="audio-url-preview"></h2>
</div>
</section>
```

here is my JS

```
   function getByID(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var recordAudio = getByID('record-audio'),
    stopRecordingAudio = getByID('stop-recording-audio');

var audio = getByID('audio');


var audioConstraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: false
};

var audioStream;
var recorder;

recordAudio.onclick = function() {
    if (!audioStream)
        navigator.getUserMedia(audioConstraints, function(stream) {
            if (window.IsChrome) stream = new window.MediaStream(stream.getAudioTracks());
            audioStream = stream;

            audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(audioStream);
            audio.muted = true;
            audio.play();

            // "audio" is a default type
            recorder = window.RecordRTC(stream, {
                type: 'audio'
            });
            recorder.startRecording();
        }, function() {
        });
    else {
        audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(audioStream);
        audio.muted = true;
        audio.play();
        if (recorder) recorder.startRecording();
    }

    window.isAudio = true;

    this.disabled = true;
    stopRecordingAudio.disabled = false;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your code only ever uses `onclick` once, it is clear that `recordAudio` is `null`.
Why? Your question only allows for speculation.

Possibly because your JavaScript is not at the bottom of your page and when it runs, the DOM tree is not built yet.